# Output is just long and not the normal 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python and trying to understand 2D arrays. I'm trying to write a code in which someone inputs and stores the employee ID, department, and salary for 10 employees. Which is then stored using a 2D array The following will be outputted:

- All the information with the appropriate column title
- How many employees are working in each department. Output it with the department name
- Input the department as accounts, admin and sales

This is my code:

```
EmpID = ""
Departement = ""
Salary = ""

EmpDetails = [[0 for c in range(3)] for r in range(4)]
for r in range(4): 
    EmpDetails[r][0]=(input("Enter the Employee ID: "))
    EmpDetails[r][1]=(input("Enter the Department: "))
    EmpDetails[r][2]=int(input("Enter the Salary: "))
print("Employee ID     Department     Salary")

for r in range(4): 
    for c in range(3): #
        print(EmpDetails[r][c], end = " ")
        print()
        Account=0
        Adcount=0
        Scount=0
        for r in range(4): 
            if EmpDetails[r][1] == "Accounts":
                Accounts=Account+1
            elif EmpDetails[r][1] == "Admin":
                Adcount=Adcount+1
            else:
                Scount=Scount+1
            print("Account: ", Account, "Employees")
            print("Admin: ", Adcount, "Employees")
            print("Sales: ", Scount, "Employees")
```

After I input my information, which is this:

```
Enter the Employee ID: 1
Enter the Department: Accounts
Enter the Salary: 1000
Enter the Employee ID: 2
Enter the Department: Admin
Enter the Salary: 2000
Enter the Employee ID: 3
Enter the Department: Sales
Enter the Salary: 3000
Enter the Employee ID: 4
Enter the Department: Accounts
Enter the Salary: 4000
```

The output comes out to be quite obnoxious and long:

```
    Employee ID     Department     Salary
1 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Accounts 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
4000 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
2 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Accounts 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
4000 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
3 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Accounts 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
4000 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
4 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Accounts 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
4000 
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  0 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  0 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
Account:  0 Employees
Admin:  1 Employees
Sales:  1 Employees
```

I don't know how to even phrase what's wrong with this. It's just long and not the 2D array output I'm looking for. I'm guessing it's something to do with lines 14 and 15 but how else would I print them out? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

this is the input part. (input like: 1,Accunts,1000 ). data will be split by comma and then converted to the required data type:

```
data = []
while True:
    if (inp := input()) != '':
        data.append([typ(value.strip()) for typ, value in zip((int, str, int), inp.split(','))])
    else:
        break
```

this is the processing part with given input data:

```
data =[[1, 'Accounts', 1000], [2, 'Admin', 2000], [3, 'Sales', 3000], [4, 'Accounts', 4000]]
depmts = {}
for item in data:
    depmts[item[1]] = depmts.get(item[1], 0) +1
for dep in depmts.items():
    print(f'{dep[0]}: {dep[1]}')
```

result:

```
Accounts: 2
Admin: 1
Sales: 1
```